# Session variables change in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have faced a confusing problem in PHP coding. it's the first time I see something like this in the past 2 years of creating websites.

assuming that I have the following two pages:

1) index.php
2) check.php

now in the `index.php` i have the following code:

```
session_start();
// 5 digit number for my captcha system
$_SESSION['my_code'] = rand(10000, 99999);
```

and now this is the code in `check.php`:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['my_code'];
```

sometimes the value of `$_SESSION['my_code']` in the `check.php` page
is different than it's value in `index.php` page. I can say every 4 or 5 times
out of 10 times.

And if I assign a constant value to my session variable in the `index.php`, I don't see this problem anymore.

Comment: `rand(10000, 99999)` Because you create a random value very time you load index.php ?! (Most posts here have an question in it and most times the question ends with a question mark)

Comment: Whatever value generated at index.php, will be shown in check.php

Comment: How  doe each get loaded? Separately?  Or included? Do you have an htaccess rewrite?

Comment: these are 2 separate pages. each contain exactly the codes I wrote in the Question.
First I navigate to index.php which sets the value. but then after each time I refresh the check.php page, it changes the value although it's not intended to.

Comment: Because you have may be the `index.php` as an entry point for every request on your site, so as @Rizier123 said you're creating a new random value every time you request `check.php` page or any other page.

Comment: Is this question still open, or has it been resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Page 1 (sessions_a.php)

First, assign a variable to the session array from the randomly generated number.

```
<?php 
session_start();
// 5 digit number for my captcha system
$_SESSION['my_code'] = rand(10000, 99999);

$var = $_SESSION['my_code'];
echo $var; // echo'd example 67859

?>

<a href="sessions_b.php">Sessions B number</a>
```

Then on page 2 (sessions_b.php) - check if it's set and do the same thing. It will echo the same number from page 1.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['my_code'])) {
    $var = $_SESSION['my_code'];
}

echo $var; // will have echo'd from example 67859
```

This has been tested successfully to echo the same number generated on the first page to the second page 20 times.

---

You can also add `session_destroy()` inside page 2 to destroy that session after it has been echo'd.

This will echo the number from page 1, but will not echo it if page 2 is reloaded afterwards.
For example: Someone reloads page 2 after coming in from page 1 after the number was echo'd.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['my_code'])) {
 session_destroy();
   echo $_SESSION['my_code']; // will only echo once, not on reloading that page
}

else{
   echo "Session's timed out.";
}
```

- It could also serve as a "one-time use", but then you would need to use a broader array of numbers in order for it to be unique, as well as adding a UNIX timestamp, microtime(), also uniqid() in order to make sure you don't get any type of repeat.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 0):

whenever index.php is rendered you change the value of session by

```
 $_SESSION['my_code'] = rand(10000, 99999);
```

and in case of constant you are restricting the value. This is why you are viewing different values.

You can assign a particular value on index and if the session is already set don't set it again... using  ISSET function of php.

Comment: these are 2 separate pages. each one contaisn exactly the codes I wrote in the Question. First I navigate to index.php which sets the value. but then after each time I refresh the check.php page, it changes the value although it's not intended to.

Comment: doesn't matter use this line instead of direct assignment 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['my_code'])) {
    $_SESSION['my_code'] = rand(10000, 99999);
}

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `$_SESSION['my_code']` to something new every time you visit `index.php`.

What you can do is this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['my_code'])) {
    $_SESSION['my_code'] = rand(10000, 99999);
}
```

Then if it isn't set, it will be a random number and if it is set, it won't re-choose a number.

Comment: these are 2 separate pages. each one  contains exactly the codes I wrote in the Question. First I navigate to index.php which sets the value. but then after each time I refresh the check.php page, it changes the value although it's not intended to.

Comment: Yes so check if it's set and if it is, don't set it again. @Agha

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time on this problem, however I found a solution.
The problem was a picture without a valid URL. I assigned the correct URL to my image and the problem was resolved.